# Container with 1:1 aspect-ratio but dynamic size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a container with a 1:1 aspect-ratio but a dynamic width/height.

There is a div at the bottom containing some text, then a div above this which fills the remaining height. This top div then contains an image with a 1:1 aspect ratio, which should have a height equal to 70% of the top div with an auto width, and should be vertically and horizontally centred.

The problem is that the `.top` div matches the height of the container, and then the image goes beyond the bounds of said container.

```css
/* CSS reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
}

img,
picture,
video,
canvas,
svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

img {
  height: auto;
}


.app {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.top img {
  height: 70%;
  width: auto;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #555;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="bottom">
        <h3>La Sportiva</h3>
        <h4>Climbing Shoe</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="top">
        <img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/www-inside-design/uploads/2020/10/aspect-ratios-blogpost-1x1-1.png">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```